# AspNet Core External Authentication with Both Google and Facebook

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, forms-authentication, google-signin, facebook-authentication

I am trying to implement the Form-Authentication in ASP.Net Core with Both Google and Facebook Authentications.  I followed some tutorials and after some struggles, I managed to make it work both.

However, the problem is that I cannot use both authentications for the same email.

For example, my email is 'ttcg@gmail.com'.
I used Facebook authentication to log in first... Registered my email and it worked successfully and put my record into 'dbo.ASPNetUsers' table.

Then I logged out, clicked on Google Authentication to log in.  It authenticated successfully, but when I tried to register it keeps saying that my email is already taken.

[image]

I tried to do the same thing for other online websites (Eg, Stackoverflow).  I used the same email for both Google and Facebook and the website knows, I am the same person and both my login / claims are linked even though they come from different places (Google & Facebook).

[image]

I would like to have that feature in my website and could you please let me know how could I achieve that.

In theory, it should put another line in 'dbo.AspNetUserLogins' and should link the same UserId with multiple logins.

Do I need to implement my own SignInManager.SignInAsync method to achieve that feature?  Or am I missing any configuration?

[image]

Comment: In the VS templates you add another provider by going to the Manage page after logging in and adding that provider, not by trying to register as a new user. Associating by e-mail address alone isn't strong enough, as the app can't verify that you really own that address.

Answer (score 1):

You need to link your Facebook external login to your Google external login with your email by using `UserManager.AddLoginAsync`, you cannot register twice using the same adresse if you use the adresse as login.
Check out the Identity sample on Identity github repo.

https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc/Controllers/ManageController.cs

To link external login to a user, the Manae controller expose methods `LinkLogin` and `LinkLoginCallback`
LinkLogin requests a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
LinkLoginCallback processes the provider response

```
    //
    // POST: /Manage/LinkLogin
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Manage");
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl, _userManager.GetUserId(User));
        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Manage/LinkLoginCallback
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> LinkLoginCallback()
    {
        var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        if (user == null)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync(await _userManager.GetUserIdAsync(user));
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageLogins), new { Message = ManageMessageId.Error });
        }
        var result = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
        var message = result.Succeeded ? ManageMessageId.AddLoginSuccess : ManageMessageId.Error;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(ManageLogins), new { Message = message });
    }
```

Comment: can you give more details? How to link FB and Google account using AddLoginAsync?

Comment: code looks the same what I have in ManageController now. What exactly should I change?

Comment: Ask a new question in stackoverflow. I don't what's your problem

Comment: I can ask, but almost sure it will marked as duplicate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158807/discussion-between-agua-from-mars-and-alexan).

Comment: yes, it's working with existing code, [this explanation](https://andrewlock.net/an-introduction-to-oauth-2-using-facebook-in-asp-net-core/#comment-3613804496) was useful